# Don't log favicon.ico errors

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, virtualhost, favicon

I run an apache2 server with some vhosts (50-100). A lot of these do not have `favicon.ico` files, cluttering the error logs with messages like

```
[Thu Mar 21 14:07:40 2013] [error] [client 84.xx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /var/www/somevhost/public_html/favicon.ico
```

Is there a way to disable logging of these errors if the file is `favicon.ico`? I've read [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/364424/disable-file-does-not-exist-var-www-html-favicon-ico) but the problem is that for that to work all vhost files need to be altered, which isn't very convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do:

```
Redirect gone /favicon.ico
RedirectMatch gone ^/apple-touch-icon
```

Apache always logs 404s as errors, even from a `Redirect`, and even if you handle them using an `ErrorDocument`. But it doesn't for 410 (`gone`), which seems an equally acceptable description of the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a 0-byte file named favicon.ico should end the flow of 404 errors.

Comment: It will for now, but as soon as a new vhost is added or the user changes the website the errors will start again, so not really a permanent solution.

Comment: Well, I guess it won't save a lot of space, but you could share the path of the 0-byte file between virtual servers.